# backbone.js for connecting model with another model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I know that in `backbone.js` you can connect View with Model. Where in Model you can update it's information by calling fetch etc. 
But in my case, I have several Views which can use common data. 
How is it possible in `backbone.js` to connect Model to some "Super" Model? 
So that I can have only one copy of data, but used at different places. And if one of the models updates the data, the "Super" Model will get that update and if needed make save to server.

If there are other than backbone.js frameworks which are better for such things, please suggest them.

Comment: Why don't you share a single model amongst your views? A view can listen to several models at once and a model can be listened to by several views at once.

Comment: @muistooshort That is what I am thinking about now. Does backbone handles such situations, when one view changes the model, and all other views that uses same data are notified?

Comment: All the listeners will get notified. You'll have to set something up yourself if you don't want a particular view to respond to an event.

Answer (score 1):

Maximus, You can define a parentModel yourself where in you can keep your common data and behavior. For example:

```
var PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // Common Data
    defaults: {
        'company' : 'SO'
    },
    // Common behavior
    getCompany: function() {
        return this.get('company');
    }
});

var EmployeeModel = PersonModel.extend({
    // Override PersonModel behavior here and define new
});
```

Comment: Will changes in EmployeeModel change appropriate fields of PersonModel and vice versa?

Comment: Nopes..If you want to sync changes in both directions, you can just use PersonModel everywhere. Just don't inherit it.

Comment: In my case I have several view-model pairs, and some data in models, not all, use common data. In order to not duplicate them in each model, I want to separate the common part in a different "super" model. If backbone doesn't sync it, then it is not useful..

Comment: btw, how about changes in one direction from EmployeeModel to PersonModel?

Comment: Yes you can do it using Backbone `listenTo` method.

Comment: So, if in one pair of view-model, the model will change the PersonModel, backbone doesn't provide means of telling about this change to all other children of PersonModel? I mean other model-view pairs which uses PersonModel as "Super" model.

Comment: There is only one way of communication between two objects which is via eventing. All the child models of PersonModel can just listenTo changes on PersonModel and take appropriate steps like rendering some part/updating some field on UI.

Comment: do you mean that in my case there should be only one model for all the views? And it will be enough for notifying view <-> model about changes?

Comment: @maximus There is no problem in having just a single model with multiple views and make your views listen to specific events on models. For example: view1 can listen to change property of name attribute in model and view2 can listen to change property of age attribute in model. For this you can use on method. See documentation for how to use `on` method in backbone.